# Disappearing TScrollBar

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi Desktop App, created with Delphi 4.
Suddenly in the last days, part of the users report about the next problem: Scroll bar disappears.
For example, in the first Img attached, yellow areas which are ok in my computer (Scroll bar with cursor) but blank for some users  (Example on 2nd picture here)

I use simple and standard TScrollBar.
I tried to change all the properties like height, width, align, visible, enable etc.
I also did not find any hint in google about this problem,
Thanks!

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88S8K.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qevj8.png)

Comment: What happens with a very small program to users who have the problem?

Comment: There is not enough details to figure out what is the real problem. That includes providing [mcve] and details about your application manifest settings (or whether it still runs as plain Win95 application) and on which particular OS your customers experience issues along with application compatibility settings.

Comment: The users who have the problem see blank area instead of Scroll bar. The have border but nothing inside, the elements inside the components not exists any more.

Comment: The OS is win10, I guess it happend after windows update

Comment: We can't help you with a problem that only occurs for some of your users, especially if it's been brought on by a Win10 update.  You need to be a bit pro-acyive with your users and see if you can get Win10 version info from them and see if they could help you by rolling back the most recent update.

Comment: @Dsm: There are no VCL styles in Delphi 4.

Comment: You should have provided two images displaying same form on customer and your computer not sharing customer view and your blank project with just some scrollbars placed on the form.

Comment: The underlying control that the scrollbar is attached to should have a corresponding BeginUpdate/EndUpdate.  Are you wrapping any modification of the data in the control within them?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same thing - in the last week, 2 users have had a disappearing scrollbar in a program compiled in Delphi 2007. The outline of the tscrollbar component is visible, but not the slider button or the arrows at each end.
[missdrawn tscrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BZtO.png)

A newer version in Delphi 10.3 worked just fine. In the newer version, runtime themes are enabled and the scrollbar is flat. In the 2007 version, there was no runtime theme and the control looks more like Windows XP.

I enabled runtime themes which changed the look of the controls and that may have solved the problem (1 user says so).

My guess is it is caused by a bug in a driver pushed out by windows update. The bug causes a problem drawing one of the legacy versions of the Win32 scrollbar control.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use delphi 4 from 1998(!) and there is no "enable runtime themes" there. do you have any idea how to disable it by other way?

Answer (score 1):

And suddenly - it works again. Most likely another Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Delphi2010. But new (created now) application with scrollbar control on the form works fine! Scrollbar is visible and I can move its button.
With older application I tried to remove all scrollbars, recompile, and add scrollbar. It is still invisible.

Comment: Yes, I guess a lot of old applications will have the same problem and as time goes on, more and more users will have windows update and scrollars will be invisible. I tried even create new project only with scroll bar, vertican and horizontal, different properties - and it's the same. As Derek Johnson wrote here, I guess the solution can be play on\off with disable\enable runtime themes but in old Delphi I can not find how to do it, there is no such an option on the project Properties. Maybe on Delphi 2010 there is, did you try to change it?

Comment: But my new application is created with Delphi2010. Old application (copied EXE file) on another computer is working fine.

Comment: I think it's because not all of the computers have the same windows update (guess). Did you try to disable\enable runtime themes, Compile again (after change it) and send to the users with the problem?

Comment: I've not found this option on my Delphi. The same EXE file copied to 4 just updated computers. 1. - Intel, Win10 - does not work; 2. - AMD, Win10 - OK; 3. - Intel, Win10 - OK; 4. - Intel, Win7 - OK;

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Delphi 10.2 32bit compile - for the 64bit compile when a form with Tscrollbars was displayed there was a delay an Windows grabbed ~5G memory.

I have fixed the issue by enabling Runtime Themes for the Project